# Pulling Out a Part of a Regular Expression (Python)

Tags: python, regex

Say I have the following regular expression and searches

```
e = r"(?P<int>\d+)|(?P<alpha_num>\w)"
num = re.search(e, "123z")
letter = re.search(e, "z123")
```

I know that `num.group("int")` gives `123` and `num.group("alpha_num")` gives `None`.
Similarly `letter.group("int")` give `None` and `letter.group("alpha_num")` give `z`

However, what I want is a way to get the "named category" for an arbitrary match.
So if I have an arbitrary match, say new_match, I could call `new_match.named_category()` and it would return "int" or "alpha_num" depending on how it matched.

Does any such command exist or do I have to create my own?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For the specific example in your question, you can use [lastgroup](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.match.lastgroup):

```
>>> import re
>>> e = r"(?P<int>\d+)|(?P<alpha_num>\w)"
>>> num = re.search(e, "123z")
>>> letter = re.search(e, "z123")
>>> num.lastgroup
'int'
>>> letter.lastgroup
'alpha_num'
```

Comment: Good answer, forgot about lastgroup.